Missing number, treated as zero for \setcounter
So I was writing something, but got the error "Missing number, treated as zero". However, the command was inserted correctly, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{3}   % zet de counter op 3 omdat hier nr. 4 moet staan
    \item \([x_1x_2]l = [x_1l,x_2] + [x_1,x_2l] \).
\end{enumerate}


Edit: I got my code down to 83 lines where it still gives the error. Sometimes when I delete some lines, the error resolves, but it can be different lines that I delete to remove the error, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
    \documentclass[twoside]{article}    % Twoside artikel omdat het boek ook per 2 pagina's is. Bovendien kunnen we zo twee verschillende kopteksten zetten, één op de even pagina's en één op de onveven pagina's. Dit is makkelijker dan bij elke pagina afzonderlijk de koptekst expliciet te plaatsen.
    \usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}       % Package voor de kop- en voettekst aan te passen.
        \pagestyle{fancy}
    \usepackage{enumitem}% Nodig om de eigenschappen van "enumerate" aan te passen, i.h.b. de "counter" in lijn 75 en 113.
    
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}       % Dit verwijdert de lijn die anders standaard onder de koptekst staat.   
    
    \newcommand{\RomanNumeralCaps}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
    
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
    
    \newcommand{\adl}{\mathrm{ad}\ l}
    \newcommand{\frM}{\mathfrak{M}}
    \newcommand{\frA}{\mathfrak{A}}
    \newcommand{\frL}{\mathfrak{L}}
    
    % ↓↓ Verandert de afstand tussen de tekst en de zijrand. Dit moet aangepast worden omdat de klasse van mijn document een tweezijdig artikel is, waardoor de tekst op linkerpagina's meer naar rechts staat, en de tekst op rechterpagina's meer naar links. Door de afstand tussen de rand op 1 inch te zetten, staat de tekst alle pagina's in het midden. 
    % Maakt de koptekst aan: op oneven pagina's "Basic concepts" en op even pagina's "Lie algebras".
    % Zet het paginanummer in de koptekst  i.p.v. voettekst. Zet de startwaarde van paginanummering op 14, van sectie naar 4 en van vergelijking op 22, zodat die overeenkomen met die van in het boek.
    
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{1in}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1in}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[CO]{\Roman{1}. BASIC CONCEPTS}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
    \fancyhead[CE]{LIE ALGEBRAS}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{}
    
    \setcounter{section}{4}
    \setcounter{page}{14}
    \setcounter{equation}{22}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \title{Exceptional Lie algebras --- opgave 42}
    \author{Nico Murania}
    \maketitle
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}   % Dit is nodig om het paginanummer op de eerste pagina te verwijderen in de voettekst.
    \headrule{\thepage} % Dit zet paginanummer 14 op de eerste pagina.
    
    \begin{center}
    
    \section{Representations and modules}
    
    \end{center}                                    %Begin van text
    \quad If $\frA$ is an associative algebra over a field $\Phi$, then a % \quad omdat de tekst niet vanzelf inspringt aangezien het zogezegd het begin van de tekst is.
    \emph{representation} of $\frA$ is a homomorphism of $\frA$ into an algebra $\mathfrak{C}$ of linear transformations of a vector space $\frM$ over $\Phi$. If \(a \rightarrow A, b \rightarrow B\) in the
    representation, then, by definition, \(a + b \rightarrow A + B, aa \rightarrow aA, a \in \Phi\), and $ab \rightarrow AB$. A \emph{right} $\frA$ module for the associative algebra $\frA$ is a
    vector space $\frM$ over $\Phi$ together with a binary product of $\frM \times \mathfrak{R}$ into $\frM$ mapping $(x,a), x \in \frM, a \in \frA$, into an element \(xa \in \frM\) such that
    \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
        \item \((x_1 + x_2)a = x_1a + x_2a,\) \quad \(x(a_1 + a_2) = xa_1 + xa_2,\)
        \item \(\alpha(xa) = (\alpha x)a = x(\alpha a),\) \quad \(\alpha \in \Phi,\)
        \item \(x(ab) = (xa)b.\)
    \end{enumerate}
    If $a \rightarrow A$ is a representation of $\frA$, then the representation space $\frM$ can be made into a right $\frA$-module by defining \(xa \equiv xA\). \ Thus we will have
    \begin{align*}
    (x_1 + x_2)a &= (x_1 + x_2)A = x_1A + x_2A = x_1a + x_2a \\
    x(a_1 + a_2) &= x(A_1 + A_2) = xA_1 + xA_2 = xa_1 + xa_2 \\
    \alpha (xa) &= \alpha (xA) = (\alpha x)A = (\alpha x)a \\
    \alpha (xA) &= x(\alpha A) = x(\alpha a) \\
    x(ab) &= x(AB) = (xA)B = (xa)b .
    \end{align*}
    Conversely, if $\frM$ is any right $\frA$-module, then for any $a \in \frA$ we let $A$ denote the mapping $x \rightarrow xa$. Then the first part of 1 and the first \, part of 2 show that $A$ is a linear transformation in $\frM$ over $\Phi$. The rest of the conditions in 1, 2, and 3 imply that $a \rightarrow A$ is a representation.
    
    In the theory of representations and in other parts of the theory of associative algebras, algebras with an identity play a preponderant role. In fact, for most considerations it is convenient to confine attention to these algebras and to consider only those homomorphisms which map the identity into the identity of the image algebra. In the sequel we shall find it useful at times to deal with associative algebras which need not have identities. We shall therefore adopt the following conventions on terminology: \emph{“Algebra” without any modifier will mean “associative algebra with an identity.”} For these "subalgebra" will mean subalgebra in the usual sense containing the identity, and "homomorphism" will mean homo-
    morphism in the usual sense mapping 1 into 1. In particular, this will be understood for representations. The corresponding notion of a module is defined by 1 through 3 above, together with the condition
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{3}   % zet de counter op 3 omdat hier nr. 4 moet staan in het boek.
        \item \(x_1 = x, \qquad x \in \frM\)
    \end{enumerate}
     If we wish to allow the possibility that t does not have an identity
    then we shall speak of the "associative algebra" $\frA$ and if we wish
    to drop 4, then we shall speak of a "module for associative algebra" rather than a module for "the algebra $\frA$"
    
    The algebra $\frA$ can be considered as a right $\frA$-module by taking
    $xa$ to be the product as defined in $\frA$. Then 1, 2, and 3 hold as
    a consequence of the axioms for an algebra and 4. holds since 1 is
    the identity. The representation $a \rightarrow A$ where $A$ is the linear transformation $x \rightarrow xa$ is called the \emph{regular representation}. We have
    seen (\S2) that the regular representation is {faithful}, that is, an isomorphism.  %er is geen sectie 2 om naar te verwijzen, vandaar gewoon de 2 i.p.v. een verwijzing.
    
    Now let $\frL$ be a Lie algebra. Then we define a \emph{representation} of $\frL$ to be a homomorphism \(l\rightarrow \frL\) of $\frL$ into a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{C}_L$, $\mathfrak{C}$ the algebra of linear transformations of a vector space $\frM$ over $\Phi$. The conditions here are that if \(l_1 \rightarrow L_1, l_2 \rightarrow L_2\) then
    \begin{align}
    \label{forumle23}
    \begin{split}
    &l_1 + l_2 \rightarrow L_1 + L_2, \; \alpha l_1 \rightarrow \alpha L_1 \\
    &[l_1,l_2] \rightarrow [L_1, L_2] \equiv L_1L_2 - L_2L_1
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
    We now define $xl$ for $x \in \frM$, $l \in \frL$ by $xl = xL$. Then \ref{forumle23} and the linearity of $L$ gives the following conditions:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \((x_1+x_2)l = x_1l + x_2l, \qquad x(l_1 + l_2) = xl_1 + xl_2,\)
        \item\(\alpha (xl) = (\alpha x)l = x(\alpha l)\)
        \item\(x[l_1l_2] = (xl_1)l_2 - (xl_2)l_1\)
    \end{enumerate}
    We shall now use these conditions to define the concept of an
    $\frL$-module, $\frL$ a Lie algebra. This is a vector space $\frM$ over $\Phi$ with a mapping of $\frM \times \frL$ to $\frM$ such that the result $xl$ satisfies 1, 2,
    and 3 above.
    
    As in the associative case, the concepts of module and representation are equivalent. Thus we have indicated that if $l \rightarrow L$ is a
    representation, then the representation space $\frM$ can be considered as a module. On the other hand, if $\frM$ is any module, then for any $l \in \frL$ we let $L$ denote the mapping $x \rightarrow xl$. Then $L$ is linear in $\frM$ over $\Phi$ and $l \rightarrow L$ is a representation of $\frL$ by linear transformations in $\frM$ over $\Phi$.
    
    We note next that $\frL$ itself can be considered as an $\frL$-module by taking $xl$ to be the product $[xl]$ in $\frL$. Then 1 and 2 are consequences of the axioms for an algebra and 3. follows from the Jacobi identity and skew symmetry. We have denoted the representing transformation of $l:x \rightarrow [xl]$ by $\adl$. The representation $l \rightarrow \adl$ determined by this module is called the \emph{adjoint representation} of $\frL$. We recall that the mappings $\adl$ are derivations in $\frL$.
    
    If $\frM$ is a module for the Lie algebra $\frL$ then we can consider $\frM$ as an abelian Lie algebra with product $[xy] = 0$. Then the mappings $x \rightarrow xl$ are linear transformations in $\frM$ and because of the triviality of the multiplication in $\frM$, these are derivations. More generally, we suppose now that $\frM$ is an $\frL$-module which is at the same time a Lie algebra, and we assume that the module mappings $x \rightarrow xl$ are derivations in $\frM$. Thus, in addition to the axioms for a Lie algebra in $\frL$ and 1, 2, and 3 above, we have also
    \begin{enumerate}
    
    \setcounter{enumi}{3}   % zet de counter op 3 omdat hier nr. 4 moet staan
    % Het kan dat hier een foutmelding gegeven wordt. De reden lijkt mij onbekend.
    \item \([x_1x_2]l = [x_1l,x_2] + [x_1,x_2l] \).
\end{enumerate}
Now let $\mathfrak{R}$ be the direct sum of the two vector spaces $\frL$ and $\frM$. We introduce in $\mathfrak{R}$ a multiplication $[uv]$ by means of the formula
\begin{align}
[x_1 + l_1, x_2 + l_2] = [x_1x_2] + x_1l_2 - x_2l_1 + [l_1l_2].
\end{align}

\end{document}


Your code works for me. Maybe give a MWE.

@garondal sorry, what is MWE?

A minimal working example. So a code I can compile (starting with \documentclass...). You gave only a snippet. If I put your code in a .tex-file I can compile without error.

see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 for more information about MWE

do not show code as an image, show it as code, you have a non standard definition of enumerate only \setcounter has been read, tex has not yet reached {enumi}{3}

I really have no idea what should be in an MWE, as I do not know what is relevant for this problem. Should I just post my entire code? Sorry, but I don't really know how things usually work on this forum.

start from a copy of your document with just the above as content, check it shows the error, then delete everything from the preamble that you can delete while showing the error and you should end up with a small complete document of a dozen or so lines that you can show here in a code block

have you loaded both enumerate and enumitem packages?

Ok so when I delete a lot (70-ish) of random lines that have nothing to do with this, the error suddenly disappears.

@DavidCarlisle yes, I have

well that will be the reason then, although I can't get the particular error you show. I would need to guess the code you hav enot shown. They both define the enumerate environment` you can not have it have two definitions at the same time, so loading both will always give errors, or do nothing useful

"Ok so when I delete a lot (70-ish) of random lines that have nothing to do with this, the error suddenly disappears. " No, when you delete the cause of the error, the error disapperars. They are not random lines, put them back and just delete half of them at a time, keeping the half that shows the error.

you cannot use \Roman{1} in your header. it gives an error as soon as you have enough content to need a second page.

@DavidCarlisle define 'cause' ....

In this case enough to cause a page break it seems

You define
\newcommand{\RomanNumeralCaps}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}

but then use
\fancyhead[CO]{\Roman{1}. BASIC CONCEPTS}

which is a syntax error, because \Roman wants a counter as argument, not an explicit number.
You likely wanted
\fancyhead[CO]{\RomanNumeralCaps{1}. BASIC CONCEPTS}

The location of the error is a bit misleading, because it's generated by a page break, not by the enumerate environment that TeX happens to be examining when the page break is triggered.

This worked, thanks so much!
